# Euler Characteristic of Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Suppose my space $X$ is a K3 surface, hence has trivial canonical bundle. Given two
coherent sheaves $F, E$ on $X$, we may define $\chi(E,F) = \sum_i (-1)^i \mathrm{ext}^i(E,F)$. I've read without proof that $\chi(E,F) = \chi(E^* \otimes F)$. I was wondering
if someone could explain where this comes from?

I thought it must come from Serre duality, but then when I calculate I get the following:
$\chi(E,F) = \sum_i (-1)^i \mathrm{ext}^i(E,F) = \sum_i (-1)^i \mathrm{ext}^i(E \otimes F^*, O_X) =
\sum_i (-1)^i h^{2-i}(X,E \otimes F^*) = \sum_j (-1)^j h^j(X,E\otimes F^*) = \chi(E \otimes F^*)$.

Comment: $Hom(E,F)\cong Hom(O_X,E^*\otimes F)$ with some conditions maybe. See Hartshorne Section III.6

Comment: That is only true when $ E $ is a vector bundle.